# Can I avoid This Cast with Generics?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I want to store an `Integer` or a `Double`, both extending from `Number`, into a `HashMap`, and retrieve them without casting.  The reason is that I'll eventually have many have many different subtypes (I am only using `Number`/`Integer` for illustration), and I don't want to have to write a new method when a different subtype is introduced.   Can I structure and call `getFromMap()` below without having to do the cast to `Double` or `Integer` ?

```
public class MapOfContent {
    static Map<String, Number> hm = new HashMap<String, Number>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addToMap(hm, Integer.valueOf(3), "An Integer");
        addToMap(hm, Double.valueOf(3.4), "A Double");

        Double d;

        d = (Double) getFromMap(hm, "A Double");
        //d = getFromMap(hm, "A Double");

        System.out.println("Result-> " + d);

    }

    private static void addToMap(Map<String, ? super Number> hashmap, Number c, String key) {
        hashmap.put(key, c);
    }

    private static <T> Number getFromMap(Map<String, ? extends Number> hashmap, String cmsKey) {
        return hashmap.get(cmsKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use Number as the type being stored in the map, you can only call methods provided by the Number class, and these are limited to intValue(), doubleValue() and so on. So your code would not be able to tell (without reflection) what type of number object was being retrieved, just that it was a Number which can provide an approximation of its value using the xxxValue() methods.

Comment: A follow-up question to this is:  Are casts frowned upon, or are they necessary and acceptable in this situation?  I have years of programming experience in other languages, but fairly new to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to actually make this approach genuinely typesafe; what if you tried `(Double) getFromMap(hm, "An Integer")`?  That *should* fail.

One potential alternative might be to use the actual `Class` object as a key, for example using a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html):

```
ClassToInstanceMap<Number> map = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();
map.putInstance(Integer.class, Integer.valueOf(3));
map.putInstance(Double.class, Double.valueOf(3.4));

Double aDouble = map.getInstance(Double.class); // no cast required
```

Comment: I am currently using Bloch's TypeSafe Heterogeneous Collection, and it works.  But I am looking for something a bit simpler.  That is analogous to Guava, I guess.  I find it cuz I use a compound key.

Comment: You're not going to find anything simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing objects of different classes in a collection and when you fetch them, you need to access fields/methods of their actual type and not just their common ancestor, then no.

There will be an explicit cast somewhere, the best you can do is to push it deep and hide it from all the other parts of the code, as `ClassToInstanceMap` does.